# Footer Won't Strech 100% across screen

Tags: html, css, footer

I am trying to get my footer (which has a background color, no background image) to always take up 100% of the viewport (or screen).  Despite everything I've tried, the footer has a gap to the right.  I figure that obviously its a width, height, padding or margin issue but I can't for the life of me figure it out.  Below is my html and css code (and before you ask or jump on me for using tables, this is the way the people who are hiring me do things.  They do a lot of html email newsletters and you have to use tables.  This is the way the html has to be done.  I realize that this isn't best practice but I am doing it the way the people who pay me want it do be done :)

Also, I need to get the unsubscribe section that is right above the footer to have the same margin on the right as it does on the left (i.e. you should be able to see the white on the left and on the right).  Maybe it is this unsubscribe section that is messing things up, I don't know.  Any help would be most appreciated (anyway, enough of my rambling, here's the code).

Here's a link to the page if you don't want to peruse the code below:

http://hoppedupdesigns.com/evolv/clients/apics/epc/form.html

HTML Code:

```
        <!-- start of unsubscribeTable div -->
            <div class="tableLeft" id="unsubscribeTable">

               <table border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top"><input type="checkbox" name="chkOptOut" id="chkOptOut"></td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="chkOptOut">Unsubscribe</label><br>
                            <p class="optout_message">Opt-out of all APICS communications</p><br>
                            <p class="optout_warning">This option will remove you from all APICS email communciations excluding transactional email and email related to membership status.</p>
                            <div>
                                <a href="#" class="button" id="cmdOptOut">Confirm Opt-Out</a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- end of unsubscribeTable div -->

        <!-- start of footer div -->
        <div id="footer">
            <p class="copyright">&copy;2013 APICS</p>
           <ul id="footerNav">
                <li><a href="http://www.apics.org/privacy-policy" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a></li>|
                <li><a href="http://www.apics.org/about/contact" target="_blank">Contact Us</a></li>|
                <li><a href="http://www.apics.org/terms-of-use" target="_blank">Terms of Use</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
        <!-- end of footer div -->

    </div>
    <!-- end of wrapper div -->

</body>
</html>

CSS Code:

body {
    line-height: 20px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;  
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

/* 1.  
*         ***** UNSUBSCRIBE SECTION *****
*/
#unsubscribeTable {
    background: #F1F1F1;
    color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    clear: left;
    padding: 30px 25px 15px 25px;
    margin: 0 0 15px 85px;
}

/* 2.  
*         ***** FOOTER *****
*/
#footer {
    background: #666;
    color: #bdbebf;
    border-top: 8px solid #838d94;
    clear: both;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 30px 25px 15px 25px;
    width: 100%;
}

#footerNav {
    float: right;
}

#footerNav li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px;
}

#footerNav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #bdbebf;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Thanks a lot guys.  You are awesome.

Jason

Comment: You should only post the code that is relevant to your problem.

Comment: I kindly suggest http://jsfiddle.net/ in the future for sharing a pared-down testcase, so that users can iterate on the problem and share then with you. Please spend time deleting your code so that you can get it down to just the bits needed to reproduce the problem. Does font color or size contribute to the problem? If not, delete them. How about that table? Oh, deleting it does change the problem? Then leave that in for us, and also think to yourself, _"Why does that particular element need to be there to cause the problem?"_

Answer (score 1):

Mimicking the behavior of the innerContent div higher on the page should help.

```
<div id='innerContent'>
  <div id='mainHeading'>
```

In the divs above, innerContent defines the padding, of 0 110px 0 110px, and then mainHeading defines a width of 100%, confined to the limits of the innerContent div.

Your unsubscribeTable is a width of 100% followed by a padding, which is greater than 100% of the screen, and causes your div to extend the page out to the right and add a horizontal scroll bar. By nesting that div within another one that limits it's width, the 100% will refer to 100% of the parent div, rather than 100% of the full page. The parent div can then define the padding. i.e.:

```
<div id='unsubscribeWrapper'>
    <div id='unsubscribeTable'>
```

Adding the following CSS, in addition to your existing unsubscribeTable CSS, will limit your unsubscribeTable width.

```
#unsubscribeWrapper {
  padding: 0 110px;
}
```

A similar problem affects the #footer. In that case, since you want your background to extend 100% of the width, you do not need a nested div. However, you can use a padding-left to offset the copyright logo from the edge of the page.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot.  That solved the problem of the footer but I still need the unsubscribe section to have the space to the right and left and drop the text down to line up with the checkboxes above it.

Answer (score 0):

in your css #footer, put padding left and right to 0 (and not 25px).

that will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
    padding: 30px 25px 15px 25px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The last [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) line is the key. Without that, your width is "100% of the positioning parent, **plus** 25px+25px", because the default box sizing model is `content-box`, where your width specifies the width of the content without padding or borders or margins.

You have another problem, however, in that content higher up in the page (`#unsubscribeTable`) is even wider than that, so you get a horizontal scroll bar that forces your page to be too wide. Again, you have specified a width along with padding for this table.

In general, I recommend thinking from the outside in: get outer containers to be the right size with the right amount of padding, and let their `display:block` (and similar) children automatically fill the width, without an explicit `width` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just saw the problem. Your unsubscribe table stretches the entire table. Just remove this line of CSS:

```
width: 100%;
```

within the #unsubscribeTable styles.